# Creating magic square

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to simplify creation magic square 3x3

```
def getCost(arr, magic):
    return sum(abs(arr[i][j] - magic[i][j]) for i in range(3) for j in range(3))

def formingMagicSquare(s):
    magic_squares = [
        [[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]],
        [[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]],
        [[2, 9, 4], [7, 5, 3], [6, 1, 8]],
        [[4, 3, 8], [9, 5, 1], [2, 7, 6]],
        [[6, 1, 8], [7, 5, 3], [2, 9, 4]],
        [[2, 7, 6], [9, 5, 1], [4, 3, 8]],
        [[4, 9, 2], [3, 5, 7], [8, 1, 6]],
        [[8, 3, 4], [1, 5, 9], [6, 7, 2]]
    ]

    minCost = float('inf')
    for square in magic_squares:
        cost = getCost(square, s)
        minCost = min(minCost, cost)
    return minCost
```

simpler way ............................

Comment: How do you define 'simpler'? It looks like a few lines of code, thus already fairly simple.

Comment: This doesn't "create" magic squares.  It just tells you the minimum Euclidean distance from the input to the arbitrary squares in your function.

Comment: What is a magic square?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use numpy, you don't need to loop over each list of lists, perform substractions element by element, or manually find the minimal value.

Using a single square `s`, when we calculate `magic_squares - s`, that substracts the elements of `s` from each element of every square in `magic_squares`.

From that difference, we calculate the `.sum(axis=1)` to go from Nx3x3 to Nx3, then `.sum(axis=1)` against to reach only N. Then we can call `.min()` on this to get the minimal cost.

```py
import numpy as np

def min_cost(s: np.ndarray) -> int:
    magic_squares = np.array([
        [[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]],
        [[6, 7, 2], [1, 5, 9], [8, 3, 4]],
        [[2, 9, 4], [7, 5, 3], [6, 1, 8]],
        [[4, 3, 8], [9, 5, 1], [2, 7, 6]],
        [[6, 1, 8], [7, 5, 3], [2, 9, 4]],
        [[2, 7, 6], [9, 5, 1], [4, 3, 8]],
        [[4, 9, 2], [3, 5, 7], [8, 1, 6]],
        [[8, 3, 4], [1, 5, 9], [6, 7, 2]]
    ])
    
    abs_diff = np.abs(magic_squares - s) # Shaped Nx3x3.
    costs = abs_diff.sum(axis=1).sum(axis=1) # Shaped N.
    return costs.min()

s = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
cost = min_cost(s)
print(cost)
# >> 24
```